# Why margin:0 auto is not aligning to center

Tags: html, css

Several times I get this problem.Whenever I try to center something using margin:0 auto.
Sometimes i succeed and sometimes not. So my questions are.

1. Why the #PostWrapper in the below example is not getting centered inside the innerWrapper.
2. When does margin:0 auto works and when it doesn't.What are the causes.

CSS:

```
#container #Post{

    background:#FFFFFF;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#container #Post #InnerWrapper{
        margin:10px;
}

#container #Post #InnerWrapper #SubjectWrapper{
    overflow:auto;
}

#container #Post #InnerWrapper #SubjectWrapper #SubjectText{
    font:30px "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
}

#container #Post #InnerWrapper #SubjectWrapper #SubjectBox{
        float:left;
        margin-left:2px;
}

#container #Post #InnerWrapper #PostWrapper{
     margin:0 auto;
     border:3px solid #000;
     display:inline-block;
}

#container #Post #InnerWrapper #PostWrapper #PostText{
     font:30px "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
     font-style:italic;
     font-weight:bold;
}

#container #Post #InnerWrapper #PostWrapper #PostBox{
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="Post">
     <div id="InnerWrapper">
    <div id="SubjectWrapper">
           <div id="SubjectText">Subject:</div>
               <div id="SubjectBox"><input type="text" class="text_box" /></div>
           </div>

        <div id="PostWrapper">
           <div id="PostText"><?php if($PageType=='and'){ echo 'Add new Deal:';}else{ echo 'Edit Company History:';}?></div>

           <div id="PostBox"><textarea rows="20" cols="103" id="PostEditor" /></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to `When does margin:0 auto works and when it doesn't.What are the causes.`? The accepted answer failed to explain that and I would be interested in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: It depends on the `position`, `width` and `display` attributes of elements.
Try putting `position: relative;` to them and also set their width.

Child divs always have a 100% width which makes centering useless, so defining width and position makes use of it. Also, you can't use `display: inline-block`, but `display: block`.

EDIT

Here is the code sample of your div using `margin: auto`: http://jsfiddle.net/vnAvk/

And here is with the inside elements also centerer (I think that's what you're after): http://jsfiddle.net/vnAvk/1/

And here's with the whole thing centered: http://jsfiddle.net/vnAvk/2/

Comment: Can we expect a `in long` version detailing why this is so?

Comment: There are numerous articles about this, coming from the people who would explain it much better than I would... Basically, divs always have a 100% width which makes centering useless, so defining width and position makes use of it.

Comment: @Shomz can you be more specific. where to put the position attribute in the above example

Comment: @Mj1992 add width and (optionally) position to the #postWrapper element... you also must use `display: block` instead of `inline-block` for it to work... let me know if you need the full code.

Comment: thnx Shomz. I am not able to work it out.I think the code option would be better.

Answer (score 1):

for two reasons: you need to clear the floating elements above it, and you have it set to display:inline-block; if you clear your floats and remove inline-block, it aligns in the center. you can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/pQhjJ/1/

Comment: it is working, u just don't have any widths set, so postwrapper is simply taking up all of innerwrappers widths. this version has a bg color on innerwrapper and a width on postwrapper http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/pQhjJ/6/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ambiguous selector, the selector chain you provided is ***invalid***. Just use

```
#PostWrapper{
     margin:0 auto;
     border:3px solid #000;
     display:inline-block;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nbj2X/)

Answer (score 1):

From what I've gathered, you may want to set a width on the parent container div because if there is no width set, it defaults to 100% for divs.  Obviously, you can't "center" a div that takes up 100% of the screen, so that should be something you try.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

And if it still dosent work than add this:

```
text-align:center;
```

Update 1:Well, while checking your styling on chrome developer tools I saw that the browser not recognizing your style refrencing so maybe the problem is on your item selecting

Update 2: Try this -

```
 #container, #Post{

    background:#FFFFFF;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#container, #Post, #InnerWrapper{
        margin:10px;
}

#container, #Post, #InnerWrapper, #SubjectWrapper{
    overflow:auto;
}

#container, #Post, #InnerWrapper, #SubjectWrapper, #SubjectText{
    font:30px "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
}

#container, #Post, #InnerWrapper, #SubjectWrapper, #SubjectBox{
        float:left;
        margin-left:2px;
}

#container, #Post, #InnerWrapper, #PostWrapper{
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     border:3px solid #000;
     display:inline-block;
}

#container, #Post, #InnerWrapper, #PostWrapper, #PostText{
     font:30px "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
     font-style:italic;
     font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion makes no sense since it is the same as the OP is using, your second suggestion is semantically wrong as it is meant for text.

Comment: IIRC the auto margin works in everything except older IE which needs the text align center bit

Comment: didn't worked. text-align aligned the heading to the center but not the textarea.

Comment: @joevallender no browser problem here. but still its not working

Comment: sorry, ie6 so fairly redundant comment ;o) well, i remember having the issue with ie6. there are better answers in the thread now anyway...